# How to read email attachment (when contentType is text/plain ) using JavaMail API

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, content-type

We have a external application, which sends us a email with attachment.
In case of contentType Multipart : we are able to parse and process the attachment.

But sometime they send mail with contentType text/plain ( message.getContent() is null), we are not able to get the attachment & email body from message obj.

Sender can't fix the content type to multipart, we have to accommodate it on receiver end.

We are using JavaMail API 1.5,tried apache commons mail util but it only works when you have object in message.getContent()

Folder emailFolder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
emailFolder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

Message[] messages = emailFolder.getMessages();
System.out.println("Total Message" + messages.length);

for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
   Message message = messages[i];

```
Multipart multipart = (Multipart) message.getContent();
 for(int k = 0; k < multipart.getCount(); k++){
   BodyPart bodyPart = multipart.getBodyPart(k);  
   InputStream stream = 
                     (InputStream) bodyPart.getInputStream();  
 }
```

}

```
**RAW MIME message content :**
  From: SENDER <SENDER@MyOrgLtd.com>
To: "'support@XYZ.com'" <'support@XYZ.com'>
Subject: Change Request #CHG85 02 ATTACHMENT
Thread-Topic: Change Request #CHG85 02 ATTACHMENT
Thread-Index: AdVQ+bdv3Fd+yaP6Qr2RCdQvPsvI9Q==
Date: Mon, 12 Aug 2019 10:37:23 +0000
Message-ID: <1dcdc97a916b4f929414d0d4b6703397@DELHIXCHMBX003.MyOrgLtd.com>
Accept-Language: en-US
Content-Language: en-US
X-MS-Has-Attach: yes
X-MS-TNEF-Correlator: 
dlp-product: dlpe-windows
dlp-version: 11.1.0.61
dlp-reaction: no-action
x-mcafeedlp-tagged: True
x-ms-exchange-transport-fromentityheader: Hosted
x-originating-ip: [IP REMOVED]
x-tm-onpremattruleprocessed: TRUE
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
    boundary="_002_1dcdc97a916b4f929414d0d4b6703397DELHIXCHMBX003MyOrgLtd_"
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-EOPAttributedMessage: 0
X-MS-PublicTrafficType: Email

X-MS-Exchange-SenderADCheck: 1
X-Microsoft-Antispam-Message-Info:  fL+9KaLob6WaIw3QlMjrWkMfgsC6D53Vr10xvjo/DWwlRA3ZuQ0emJtxG2R1r3GXNuLYK7l6vjv/buJaaPhR7VW5qdysbinenPJjyOIwCcTuBCAm1nAtlEWJqRzIJT0n7oxDQvh7pH+mIm7yK0BwYX8nJyfg2CSot7is9h/Xbk/uwYow4RW9IuSq5ioMCPSt+zRzdfbJ76DIPvne4FYRy+D8Xbe4RBMcf6u7wvtQW3n86JtRUVz1EjDGmIA6ZfyHXtYf3Q09VKfyMg6wa7KOWJaiU+6HJCY4Jevdxgy75xvR+56PCQ1dV0QgeMsEqVuKrM0YndKVKrF3u08rO7PQoTpv37z4xqRyTNRpTwLXeuQWi6tBFRk3HjrbBKBaRpme1On2cYRFBCiXMLMxBfpNIaR4lolZ0MPL/h3UANKY7r4=
X-OriginatorOrg: MyOrgLtd.com
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-OriginalArrivalTime: 12 Aug 2019 10:37:25.6885
 (UTC)
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-Network-Message-Id: 8137d2d0-3ec5-4a61-f117-08d71f111117
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-Id: edf442f5-b994-4c86-a131-b42b03a16c95
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-OriginalAttributedTenantConnectingIp: TenantId=edf442f5-4c86-a131;Ip=[IP RMOVED];Helo=[MyEmail.MyOrgLtd.com]
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-FromEntityHeader: HybridOnPrem
X-MS-Exchange-Transport-CrossTenantHeadersStamped: BMXPR01MB3830
X-CLX-Shades: MLX
X-CLX-Response: 1TFkXExoRCkx6Fx4SEQpZRBdlfmFZE0V5WUNGUBEKWFgXaWZ9aWdnaUtyflI RCnhOF20SRWsbeENtRk5hEQp5TBdrf0BAcxJBGGIcaBEKeUMXaVNsSG1kWF5yZhoRCkNIFwcYGR oRCkNZFxsfGBEKWU0XZ2ZyEQpZSRcacRoQGncGHRpxHhAadwYYGgYaEQpZXhdobnkRCklGF0teX
 nVCRVleT04RCkNOF3l1T25TfGVCe1xEfF1NWlBbbx9abRtsc0BbY1lGXlATEQpYXBcfBBoEGxIb BxNMGhwTThIfBRsaBBsaGgQeEgQcEBseGh8aEQpeWRd/Ql9zbBEKTVwXGx0eEQpMWhdoaU1raxE KTEYXb2tra2traxEKQk8XaUVwGwFzWHhPG0gRCkNaFx4aBBsaHQQbGRIEGxkbEQpCXhcbEQpEXh
 cYEQpCXBcaEQpCRRdsSWtYGWwcf2RTSxEKQk4XbRJFaxt4Q21GTmERCkJMF2lmfWlnZ2lLcn5SE QpCbBdhbXkfU2Z4b25DSBEKQkAXZmlOYEBgbVNLW3IRCkJYF3pAbVgfbnhkHUUfEQpNXhcbEQpa WBcYEQpwaBdiXEcaUG98Q15ERxAZGhEKcGgXYWFAa0FNbENaQBgQHBoRCnBoF2UFeGZtGXppaB5
 pEB0aEQpwaBdjeEllXmZ8fUkSBRAdGhEKcGgXY0VPSWJSfWBdUEAQGRoRCnBrF21pQXNffU8BBQ FuEBkaEQpwSxdhUBIbAU9saERdBRAZGhEKcGsXY2dsAWlvYXN5YnkQGRoRCnBsF2drQ2lPeV9DR xJBEBkaEQpwQxdsSx1AEl9bTQVrRBAcHREKbX4XGxEKWE0XSxEg
X-Proofpoint-SPF-Result: pass
X-Proofpoint-SPF-Record: v=spf1 mx ip4:IP RMOVED ip4:IP RMOVED
 ip4:IP RMOVED ip4:IP RMOVED ip4:IP RMOVED
 ip4:IP RMOVED include:spf2.MyOrgLtd.com
 include:spf.protection.outlook.com -all
X-Proofpoint-Virus-Version: vendor=fsecure engine=2.50.10434:,, definitions=2019-08-12_04:,,
 signatures=0
X-Proofpoint-Spam-Reason: safe
--_002_1dcdc97a916b4f929414d0d4b6703397DELHIXCHMBX003MyOrgLtd_
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

hi User,
    We have received the data, will process and inform you.

Thank you,
admin


--_002_1dcdc97a916b4f929414d0d4b6703397DELHIXCHMBX003MyOrgLtd_
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name="testData.csv"
Content-Description: testData.csv
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="testData.csv"; size=393;
    creation-date="Mon, 12 Aug 2019 10:35:38 GMT";
    modification-date="Mon, 12 Aug 2019 10:35:38 GMT"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

IkNpcmN1aXQgIiwiU2V2ZXJpdHkiCiJDaXJjdWl0OSAgICAvU0EgIC8iLCJPdXRhZ2UiCiJDaXJjdWl0MTQgICAgL1NMICAvIiwiT3V0YWdlIgoiQ2lyY3VpdDggICAgL1NCICAvIiwiT3V0YWdlIgoiQ2lyY3VpdDUgICAgL1NCICAvIiwiT3V0YWdlIgoiQ2lyY3VpdDYgICAgL1NUICAvIiwiT3V0YWdlIgoiQ2lyY3VpdDcgICAgL1NCICAvIiwiT3V0YWdlIgoiQ2lyY3VpdDIgICAgL1NHICAvIiwiT3V0YWdlIgoiQ2lyY3VpdDUxICAgIC9TQiAgLyIsIk91dGFnZSIKIkNpcmN1aXQxICAgIC9TTSAgLyIsIk91dGFnZSIKIkNpcmN1aXQ0ICAgIC9TQiAgLyIsIk91dGFnZSI=

--_002_1dcdc97a916b4f929414d0d4b6703397DELHIXCHMBX003MyOrgLtd_--
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the content type is text/plain, there is no attachment.

And if message.getContent() is returning null, there's probably no message content either, or something is wrong with the formatting of the message.  Post the raw MIME content of the message and I can help you figure what's wrong with the message.

Comment: I have updated the raw MIME content of message,  I can see the message body & attachment (base64 String) in raw content.
getContentType() returns text/plain & getContent() is null.
Now how to get the body & attachment?

Comment: There's a few problems with the message.  The To address is invalid.  I'll ignore that problem.  There's a blank line after the `X-MS-PublicTrafficType: Email` line.  Possibly you have an anti-virus product that has filtered and modified the message incorrectly?  Even with that problem, JavaMail is able to parse the message and see the attachment.  Perhaps your mail server is not able to parse the message?  What mail server are you using?  Can you post the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug) when accessing this message?

Comment: Thanks Bill, my local antivirus was interfering with the message. I deployed code on different environment  & message.getContent() start returning correct object.
Issue resolved.